# OpenSSL error installing ruby 2.0.0-p195 on Mac with rbenv

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0.0-p195 using rbenv on a Mac (Mountain Lion) and got this error.

```
BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/vt/27n8h2yj27v7rzq58075f3_m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130618163859.1669
Results logged to /var/folders/vt/27n8h2yj27v7rzq58075f3_m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130618163859.1669.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specifications)
                              bigdecimal 1.2.0
                              io-console 0.4.2
                              json 1.7.7
                              minitest 4.3.2
                              psych 2.0.0
                              rake 0.9.6
                              rdoc 4.0.0
                              test-unit 2.0.0.0
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

When I ran brew install openssl it said

```
Warning: openssl-1.0.1e already installed
```

Following a solution on this thread https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/305 I tried to install latest stable this way and got the same error

```
env CFLAGS='-g -O2' RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline`" rbenv install 2.0.0-p195
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding OpenSSL to the config options using the **--with-openssl-dir** option:

```
$ CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install 2.0.0-p195
```

If you're using Homebrew, you'll need to install OpenSSL before running the above by running:

```
$ brew install openssl
```

**UPDATE** *(see @JarkkoLaine 's comment below)*:

> Just for the record, you should not need to use the config opts
>   anymore with ruby-build and homebrew. However, I had to reinstall
>   openssl with homebrew to make it work: brew uninstall openssl; brew
>   upgrade; brew install openssl; rbenv install 2.0.0-p247. See [this](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/377#issuecomment-27159797) for
>   more info.

Comment: I had to also do `brew install curl-ca-bundle; export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt` to get it to work.

Comment: Just for the record, you should *not* need to use the config opts anymore with ruby-build and homebrew. However, I had to reinstall openssl with homebrew to make it work: `brew uninstall openssl; brew upgrade; brew install openssl; rbenv install 2.0.0-p247`. See [this](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/377#issuecomment-27159797) for more info.

Comment: @JarkkoLaine 's solution of re-installing openssl via homebrew solved it for me (and after re-installing, I don't need to set the env variable either). I suspect it might be related to me recently upgrading to OS X Mavericks, which modified a lot of file permissions and ownerships in /usr/local. Perhaps you could consider promoting this comment to an answer, to make it easier to spot?

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this by executing:

```
brew link openssl --force
```

Mac OSX 10.9.4

Comment: This little thing saved me an all-nighter

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @stopshinal Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading to the latest version of ruby-build fixed the problem for me:

Like the OP, I got

```
BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /Users/me/.rbenv/sources/2.0.0-p247
Results logged to /var/folders/3x/y_8y8vr53ws_kxj97km79q5h0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130704172404.3106.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specifications)
                              bigdecimal 1.2.0
                              io-console 0.4.2
                              json 1.7.7
                              minitest 4.3.2
                              psych 2.0.0
                              rake 0.9.6
                              rdoc 4.0.0
                              test-unit 2.0.0.0
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

but installing the latest version of ruby-build, via

```
# Don't forget brew doctor and brew update if required
brew upgrade ruby-build
```

fixed it.

Ruby-build had some changes between when the OP asked and now, which would explain why it worked for me, but not for the OP using the latest stable version of ruby-build.

Comment: Make sure you run `brew update` to update your formulae so you get the latest version of `ruby-build` when you upgrade/install :)

Comment: @electblake I noted that above the command for "brew upgrade ruby-build".

Comment: I just installed the latest brew with rbenv and ruby-build and this didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Voted up because upgrading ruby-build solved this for me!

I installed rbenv via git (not Brew,) however I did essentially the same thing as @Andrew by directly upgrading rbenv and ruby-build:

`$ cd ~/.rbenv`
`$ git pull`
`$ cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`
`$ git pull`

When I ran "rbenv install 2.0.0-p353" the first thing that happened was that a new version of openssl was installed, and the ruby install worked fine.

As a side-benefit, upgrading ruby-build also updated my list of installable Ruby versions.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have problems installing openssl.

I had this error on my Mac 10.8.4

```
brew install openssl

created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/include/openssl'
make: *** [install_sw] Error 13

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/19429
```

1. Create a directory if it does not exist

   ```sh
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/openssl
   ```
2. Change the rights. Replace  and  with your name and group (e.g. serge:admin)

   ```sh
   sudo chown -R <username>:<group> /usr/local/etc/openssl/
   ```
3. Repeat openssl installation

   ```sh
   brew install openssl
   ```
4. Install curl-ca-bundle

   ```sh
   brew install curl-ca-bundle
   ```
5. install ruby

   ```sh
   CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install 2.0.0-p195
   ```

Bingo

Comment: Step 1 fixed it for me. I actually did these steps with brew install openssl running, and the directory was made just in time I guess because at the point when it usually failed, the brew install kept going! Bingo

Answer (score 1):

Solution using ruby-install:

After uninstalling and installing openssl a couple of times (probably unnecessary) I successfully tried this:

```
ruby-install ruby 2.1.3 -- --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing library is libssl**-dev** / openssl**-dev**, depending your distribution.

Comment: FWIW, He's on OS X, not a Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue came up again for me with Mac OS 10.9.5**

Mac upgraded the command-line tools and that upgraded openssl, which broken rbenv.

I tried all of these solutions, but none of them worked. Everything was up-to-date, but I couldn't install any new gems or build rubies.

My solution was to:

1. Remove the ruby version (for me it was 2.1.1)
2. Brew uninstall ruby-build and rbenv
3. Brew Re-install rbenv and ruby-build

Hope this helps you if you encounter it too!