# Gem install error due to invalid ssl using rbenv

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, homebrew

I'm trying to install a new gem (`gem install lunchy`), but am getting the following error due to the ssl certificate:

`ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method 'invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass`

I've tried a number of fixes:

Tried `gem update --system` per this answer [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error) but get the same error on that command.

Tried `brew install openssl` followed by `brew link openssl --force` per this question but to no avail: [OpenSSL error installing ruby 2.0.0-p195 on Mac with rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181075/openssl-error-installing-ruby-2-0-0-p195-on-mac-with-rbenv)

Even tried reinstalling rbenv and ruby but that didn't work either, still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby being executed in this error is not one installed by `rbenv`, but by Homebrew.

If you're trying to use `rbenv`, maybe run `brew uninstall ruby` and/or check the output of `echo $PATH` to make sure that `~/.rbenv/shims` is at the start.